# Looking for an elegant way to copy cherry-picked objects from one database to another

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-connection

I'm doing a database restore of specific objects that were destroyed. There's roughly a hundred of them. Is there an elegant way to perform this?

Ideally, I'd love to do a command such as : `Object.where(attribute: 'condition')` , and then copy the console output, and be able to console into the other database and create all my objects off of that output..

Any recommends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just dealing with plain data, you might try one of three approaches.

**Export/Import CSV**

The pure database approach is to select from your various tables into an export file you can use to later re-load on the other end.

For example:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... INTO OUTFILE 'export.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED  BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

This creates a CSV-formatted export file you can later re-load on the other system:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'export.csv' INTO TABLE ... FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED  BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

This requires direct access to your MySQL server, but it's very fast if successful. `BINARY` or `BLOB` type fields do not work with CSV as they conflict with the delimiters.

**Export/Import YAML**

Every model is capable of outputting itself as serialized YAML. You can basically dump all of the objects you need on one end, then re-load on the other.

```
File.open('dump.yml', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(Object.where(:attribute => 'condition').all.to_yaml)
end
```

You can re-load these on the other end:

```
File.open('dump.yml') do |f|
  Object.transaction do
    YAML.load(f).each do |attributes|
      Object.create!(attributes)
    end
  end
end
```

The `Object.transaction` part means either all records get added or none do, so if there's an error you can correct it and run the script again without conflict.

**SQL Dump/Restore**

The `mysqldump` command takes a `--where` argument that can be used to filter records:

```
mysqldump database table --no-create-db --no-create-info --where `attribute='condition'` > table.sql
```

This should have just `INSERT` statements, but check to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the backup database to your `database.yml`, read your objects from it, switch back to the main database and re-create the missing objects. Something like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:backup_database)

objects = Object.where(attribute: 'condition')

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:master_database)

objects.each { |object| Object.create! object.attributes }
```

Comment: How would one refer to one database over the other?

Comment: `backup_database` and `master_database` are the databases defined in your `database.yml`, just like `development` or `production`.

Comment: Ah ok, but from console, how would I select objects from just one of those databases as opposed to the other when doing `Object.where..` ?

Comment: `establish_connection` sets the database for subsequent reads and writes, so you establish a connection to your backup database, read the objects into memory, establish a connection to your production (or whatever) database and write the objects from memory back to the (other) database.